特定の Andoroid スマートフォンからのみ、xhrhttprequest で 動画をアップロード出来ない
起こっている事
特定の Android のスマートフォン実機からのみ、動画ファイルを xhrhttprequest で送信できません。
PC、iOS スマートフォン実機、その他の Android のスマートフォン実機 からは同じ動画ファイルを同じコードで送信出来ています。
補足など
手元に対象エラーが起こっている実機が無く、別担当の方のテストAndroid実機でのみ再現する状況です。どうやら新しい Android OS だと失敗する傾向が見えていますが、家族に借りた 新しいAndroid 実機（OSバージョンを控えていませんでした）でテストすると成功しているので、必ず失敗する訳でも無いようです。
その担当の方に依頼して、USBで実機をPC接続し、Chrome デベロッパーツールでのデバッグを行ったものの、特に不明なデータも見つけられず、手詰まり感のある状態です。
同様のご経験などある方がいらっしゃいましたら、ヒント等、些細な事でもご教示頂けないでしょうか。
どうぞ、よろしくお願い致します。
追記
次の情報に沿って、php.ini の設定を見直してみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。念のため、関連値も記載しておきます。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103334/xmlhttprequest-file-upload-not-working-on-mobile
memory_limit => 2G
upload_max_filesize => 2G
max_input_vars => 1000 
max_execution_time => 0
; post_max_size = 8M (変更前)
post_max_size = 64M (変更後)

ウェブアプリ環境
サーバー
・CentOS Linux 7
・nginx 1.20.1
フロント
・Javascript
バック
・PHP 7.3
・cakephp 3.8
検証状況
送信成功するデバイス
PC（Windows 10 Pro）
Android 6.0.1
Android 8.0.0
iOS 16.2
送信失敗するデバイス
Android 11
Android 13
送信コード（Javascript）
// 関連箇所のみ抜粋

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('upfile', upfile); // upfile = アップロードする動画ファイル ---①

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304) && xhr.response) {
        var data = xhr.response;

        console.log( 'COMPLETE! :' );
        console.log( data );
    } else {
        console.log( 'Failed. HttpStatus: '+xhr.status );
    }
};

xhr.open('POST', '/api/video/upload', true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';

xhr.send(fd);

送信ログ（Javascript）
送信直前の上記、---①の箇所で、処理を止めて確認した upfile のデータです。
この時点では、ファイルデータが upfile に入っています。
# upfile
lastModified: 1713564962045
lastModifiedDate: Sat Apr 20 2024 07:16:02 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)
[[Prototype]]: Object
name: "VID_2024-04-20-07-15-56-811.mp4"
size: 10950674
type: "video/mp4"
webkitRelativePath: ""

受信コード（cakePHP3.8）
//src\Controller\Api\VideosController.php

public function upload(){

    // 失敗する端末からの送信時は、すでにこの時点でデータを取得出来ていない
    $this->appInfoLog("api.videos.upload",
        ["request"=>$this->request,
            "_FILES"=>$_FILES,
        ]
    );
    
    // 以下アップロード処理
    // ...
 }

受信ログ（cakePHP3.8）
成功時　_FILESにデータが入っています。
2024-04-20 05:53:13 Info: {"request":{"trustProxy":true},"_FILES":{"upfile":{"name":"VID_20240419_155656.mp4","type":"video\/mp4","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpAu0ege","error":0,"size":7330740}},"action":"api.videos.upload"}

 

失敗時　_FILESが空です。
2024-04-20 06:31:52 Info: {"request":{"trustProxy":true},"_FILES":[],"action":"api.videos.upload"}


最終的に、/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf (*はサービス名称) 内に、
client_max_body_size　の項目を追加する事で解決致しました。
Android モバイル端末は、送信時にファイルサイズが膨れ上がるのでしょうか、、、
行った事
・cakephp のログだけでなく、PHPのデフォルトのログを出力して確認した（出力設定がされていなかった）
・php-fpm 設定ファイル、nginx の 設定ファイル の POST に関連する値を修正した
・php-fpm, nginx の再起動
/etc/opt/remi/php73/php-fpm.d/www.conf
memory_limit => 2G
upload_max_filesize => 2G
max_input_vars => 2000
max_execution_time => 0
post_max_size = 500MB


/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf (*はサービス名称)
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  // 追加
  client_max_body_size 500MB;
}

php-fpm, nginx の再起動
systemctl restart php73-php-fpm.service
systemctl reload nginx

